# Call to a member function attach() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I want to make a tag system byt I have an error "Call to a member function attach() on null". I have a 2 table - person and persontags. Relationships look like this:

```
//in person
public function tags(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\persontags');
    }
//in persontags
    public function person(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\person');
    }
```

I created table person_persontags too.In controller I want to use attach method:

```
$person->tags()->attach($request->tags);
```

but I have this error.
PS. My view look like this:

```
<select class="js-example-responsive col-12" multiple="multiple" name="tags[]">
            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                <option value={{ $tag->id }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
</select>
```

How can I solve my problem?

@Edit
$person var is not null becouse I create a new person:

```
$person = person::create([
'name' => $request->name,
//...
]);
$person->tags()->attach($request->tags);
```

@Edit2

Resoult of dd($request->tags)

[image]

Comment: Could you specify file names regarding their own characters case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a relation type object from your relationship methods. For it to be a relationship method it must return a Relation Type object (HasOne, HasMany, BelongsTo, etc etc).

You are returning nothing so `void|null`, you should return from the method:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\persontags');
    // `belongsToMany` returns an object
}

public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\person');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you echo the `$request->tags` before `attach()` by writnig this:

```
dd($request->tags);
$person->tags()->attach($request->tags);
```

@edit

@Konfus2234 Well i think what could cause the error is the name of tables, so what you can do is specify the name of table like that:

```
public function tags(){
$this->belongsToMany('App\persontags', 'name_of_table');
}
public function person(){
$this->belongsToMany('App\person', 'name_of_table');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because the `$person` variabel is return `null`. Check your `$person` value, is it `null` or not?